# In general, is it good practice to fail a REST request if the request body includes extra parameters?

Tags: rest, web

e.g. for the following POST request

```
POST: /someListOfObjects/
BODY: {
    correctProperty: 'good value',
    extraProperty: "this property doesn't map to the underlying entity"
}
```

Should the API return a `400: Bad Request`, or just ignore the `extraProperty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the correct answer is: **it depends**.

But I would definitely chose to ignore the `extraProperty` most of the time. The beautiful thing about REST APIs is that they are flexible, and you can make them backward and forward compatible without much trouble. So, if you end up restricting too many things on clients, it will probably be a little bit more difficult to make changes without breaking existing clients.

Also, most of the time I would not use posting a **JSON** object directly to my API. I would use form encoding, and get the parameters, one by one.

Comment: Could you expand upon your reasons against a JSON object in the body vs form encoded query parameters?

Comment: I just think it's an easier to use API if you use form parameters directly. There is nothing essentially wrong with posting the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's settled in the community. My personal preference would be to return an error code. Whatever you do, be consistent across the entire API.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of factors that I use to determine how strict I should be with an API:

1. Versioning - Is the API supposed to be backwards/forwards compatible? If so, then ignoring extra properties might not only be a good decision, it is probably one of the only ways you can support version compatibility.
2. Security - Is your API supposed to be a trusted service? If it is an authentication API, for instance, it might not make sense to have such a relaxed input policy.

Answer (score 1):

If I go to a bank to withdraw money but talk constantly about the weather with the cashier while I'm doing it, I should still get my money.

For most applications, extra parameters could easily be ignored. If you want to write a stricter application then put something extra in the response payload that hints to the client that they aren't doing things perfectly correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Cherry pick the ones you want, make sure they're safe and secure, and throw away the rest if you're not using it or them.